# How to move Checkbox checked method to other Form?

Tags: winforms, checkbox, controls

I have a mini setup program written using Windows Forms and C# and have a problem.

I have four CheckBox controls and I want to get checked info and use it on another form 
so it provides which checkbox is checked. The other form shows only checked module list based on which check boxes are checked.

How can I show only checked modules in Form2?

Comment: didn't understood your question... what do want to pass to form2?

Comment: please clarify your question, possibly adding some code

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass that information into the second form.

So, on `From2` you can add a method that takes a list of `bool` values or similar and make this method public.

```
 // put this method in Form2
 public void SetModules(IList<bool> modulesEnabled)
 {
     // here you can test whether a certain module is enabled
     //    by checking modulesEnabled[0], modulesEnabled[1], etc.
 }
```

From Form1, before showing From2 you would get the state of the checkboxes and construct the modulesEnabled array. Then invoke SetModules on Form2.

```
 Form2 secondForm = new Form2();

 IList<bool> modulesList = new List<bool>();
 modulesList.Add(checkBox1.Checked);
 modulesList.Add(checkBox2.Checked);
 modulesList.Add(checkBox3.Checked);
 modulesList.Add(checkBox4.Checked);

 secondForm.SetModules(modulesList);      // make sure to call this BEFORE showing Form2

 secondForm.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

until i'll know more i'll give you some ideas:

`Form2` can have in his constructor, get `Form1` and have `Form1` give a method like so:

```
  public bool IsCheckboxChecked(int checkIndex)
  {
     if (checkIndex == 1)
     {
        return checkBox1.Checked;
     }
     else if (checkIndex == 2)
     {
        return checkBox2.Checked;
     }
     else if (checkIndex == 3)
     {
        return checkBox3.Checked;
     }
     else if (checkIndex == 4)
     {
        return checkBox4.Checked;
     }
     else
     {
        return false;
     }
  }
```